# How to fix dreaded type mismatch required _$1 when modifying the class containing the generic is not an option?

Tags: java, scala, generics

I'm working with a Java library and one class is defined as follows:

```
public interface Client<C extends Credentials> {
  //...
  C getCredentials(WebContext context);
  Object getUserProfile(C credentials, WebContext context);
}
```

Now in Scala I wrote:

```
//foundClient: Client[_ <: Credentials]
val credentials = foundClient.getCredentials(context) //returns a _ <: Credentials
val profile = foundClient.getUserProfile(credentials, context)
//compiler not happy because it cannot be sure that the real type of `credentials` is the same as the generic type of `foundClient`
```

which, of course, throws `type mismatch found: credentials.type required: _$1`.
If I could modify the `Client` interface, it would be easy to add `def getUserProfile(context: WebContext) = getUserProfile(getCredentials(context), context)` but I can't.

I had a look at using `TypeTag` but I didn't get very far.
Additionally, what is strange is that Java is perfectly happy with the code above as if there was no type erasure...

Help!

Comment: what is the type of `foundClient` resp. how was it created?

Comment: `foundClient` is a `Client[_ <: Credentials]` and `Credentials` is an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that the compiler cannot connect the types of your credential with the required parameter - they might in theory be different, after all. Fixing the type of the client parameter by introducing a "forwarder" fixes this issue:

```
trait Credential
trait Client[C] {
  def credential: C
  def getUserProfile(name: String, credential: C): Any
}


object Foo extends App {
  val foundClient: Client[_ <: Credential] = ???

  def getUserProfile[A](client: Client[A], name: String): Any = {
    val credential = client.credential
    client.getUserProfile(name, credential)
  }

  getUserProfile(foundClient, "Foo")
}
```